# Boost `interval_map` - how to customize aggregating on touch

Tags: c++, boost-icl

The Boost ICL `interval_set` can join *right-open* intervals, which **touch each other**, during adding them to the set. For example, intervals `[0,4)` and `[4,8)` will be joined to become an interval `[0,8)`.

This is more complicated for the `interval_map` - intervals, which touch each other and have different associated values, won't be joined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

using IMap = icl::interval_map<int, int>;

int main()
{
  IMap m;
  m += std::make_pair(IMap::interval_type::right_open(0, 4), 1);
  m += std::make_pair(IMap::interval_type::right_open(4, 8), 2);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Output of this test program is below:

```
{([0,4)->1)([4,8)->2)}
```

I know how to customize the process of *aggregating on overlap*, however I need to customize another case - **aggregating on touch**. For example, if intervals touch each other **and** value of the left interval is equal to the value of the right interval **minus 1**, then intervals must be joined, and the resulting interval must have a value of the left interval. So, the program above should print:

```
{([0,8)->1)}
```

Is it possible to do that with currently available Boost ICL?

I can do what I want using weird manipulations with the `interval_map`, but I think it'd be cumbersome and non-efficient. I'd prefer to be pointed in right direction to use currently available ICL customizations, functors etc.

Answer (score 1):

> This is more complicated for the interval_map - intervals, which touch each other and have different associated values, won't be joined:

There's no difference, really.

> I know how to customize the process of aggregating on overlap, however I need to customize another case - aggregating on touch.

You seem to imply that

```
 m += std::make_pair(IMap::interval_type::right_open(4, 8), 2);
```

will insert `[4, 8) -> 2`.

That's simply not the case. It's a codomain combination operation, and the results depend on prior state of the map.

Of course, you can write it:

```
m.set({Ival::right_open(4, 8), 2});
```

If you need to, you can query the preceding slot, so your operation might look like:

```
// returns true if joined with preceding slot
bool fill_slot(IMap& m, int from, int till, int value) {
    bool joined = false;
    auto slot = Ival::right_open(from, till);

    if (within(slot, m)) {
        // There is overlap, I don't know how  you want to handle this.
        // You can add some logic here.
    } else {
        auto preceding = m(from - 1);

        if (preceding && value == preceding + 1) {
            joined = true;
            value = preceding;
        }
    }

    m.set({slot, value});
    return joined;
}
```

Now you can write test cases like:

```
int main() {
    {
        IMap m;
        fill_slot(m,  0,  4,  1);
        fill_slot(m,  4,  8,  2);
        std::cout << m << std::endl;
    }
    {
        IMap m;
        fill_slot(m,  0,  4,  1);
        fill_slot(m,  4,  8,  3);
        std::cout << m << std::endl;
    }
    {
        IMap m;
        fill_slot(m,  0,  4,  1);
        fill_slot(m,  5,  8,  2);
        std::cout << m << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And they print **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c538c4c032d61c9c)</kbd>**

```
{([0,8)->1)}
{([0,4)->1)([4,8)->3)}
{([0,4)->1)([5,8)->2)}
```

Comment: Sorry to say - your `fill_slot` function is what I was trying to avoid asking this question. The ICL `interval_map` has eight template arguments - I hoped I could use them to customize the map in a way I need. For example - to use non-default functors, or to write my own ones. Or - to customize the `interval` type itself...

Comment: Hoping doesn't really help a lot. See [Laws for Quantifiers of signed Numbers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/semantics/quantifiers__maps_of_numbers.html#boost_icl.semantics.quantifiers__maps_of_numbers.laws_for_quantifiers_of_signed_numbers) "Customizing" the map to do other things will just make the behaviour undefined. If you understand in which your special-purpose semantics can fit these laws, then go for it. But as for now, I don't think it can (and a lot of details aren't described).

Comment: From where I'm sitting it looks like you have two things: an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on the one hand and a proper learning project on the other hand (Boost ICL). I think that's awesome. The library must be one of the most underrated Boost libraries. I'm just not sure it holds a canned solution. Neither am I sure why you would want it to (if you go outside the designated purpose of the library and supposing the library **would** facilitate is, wouldn't you lose all the complexity guarantees that made it attractive in the fist place?)

Comment: The ICL looks like highly adaptable library, including its "aggregating on overlap" concept. Why there no "aggregating on touch" functionality? I hoped that more deeply involved in the ICL people could help me to find a way to where it's hidden